# How often should the indexes be rebuilt in our SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2005, maintenance-plan

Currently our database has size 10 GB and is growing by around 3 GB per month. Often I hear that one should from time to time rebuild the indexes, to improve the query execution time. So how often should I rebuild the indexes in the given scenario?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There's a general consensus that you should reorganize ("defragment") your indices as soon as index fragmentation reaches more than 5 (sometimes 10%), and you should rebuild them completely when it goes beyond 30% (at least that's the numbers I've heard advocated in a lot of places).

Michelle Ufford (a.k.a. "SQL Fool") has an [automated index defrag script](http://sqlfool.com/2009/03/automated-index-defrag-script/), which uses those exact limits for deciding when to reorganize or rebuild an index.

Also see [Brad McGehee's tips on rebuild indexes](https://www.sql-server-performance.com/rebuilding-indexes) with some good thoughts and tips on how to deal with index rebuilding.

---

I use this script here (can't remember when I got this from - whoever it was: many thanks! Really helpful stuff) to display the index fragmentation on all your indices in a given database:

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME 'Table name',
    i.NAME 'Index name',
    ips.index_type_desc,
    ips.alloc_unit_type_desc,
    ips.index_depth,
    ips.index_level,
    ips.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
    ips.fragment_count,
    ips.avg_fragment_size_in_pages,
    ips.page_count,
    ips.avg_page_space_used_in_percent,
    ips.record_count,
    ips.ghost_record_count,
    ips.Version_ghost_record_count,
    ips.min_record_size_in_bytes,
    ips.max_record_size_in_bytes,
    ips.avg_record_size_in_bytes,
    ips.forwarded_record_count
FROM 
    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED') ips
INNER JOIN  
    sys.tables t ON ips.OBJECT_ID = t.Object_ID
INNER JOIN  
    sys.indexes i ON ips.index_id = i.index_id AND ips.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
WHERE
    AVG_FRAGMENTATION_IN_PERCENT > 0.0
ORDER BY
    AVG_FRAGMENTATION_IN_PERCENT, fragment_count
```

Comment: The link to Brad McGhee's tips is broken. Maybe this is the correct link, http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/rebuilding-indexes/

Comment: There's also [Ola Hallengren's SQL Server Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/), which has a statistics and index management procedure.  It also defaults to 5% reorganize/30% rebuild.

Comment: It's better to use sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'LIMITED') and focus on just the fragmentation columns.
DETAILED is between 20 to 500 times slower depending on the DB size. and you get a lot of useless information column (useless to determine fragmentation)

Answer (score 7):

"When you need to" and "When you can"!

For example...

- Test for fragmentation first and decide whether to do nothing, reorg or rebuild.
  [SQL Fool's script does this](http://sqlfool.com/2009/06/index-defrag-script-v30/), for example, has `@minFragmentation` and `@rebuildThreshold` parameters
- Do statistics daily, say, but indexes at weekends. What is your maintenance window?

Answer (score 4):

You should rebuild indexes often enough so that production is not detrimentally affected by index degradation. I understand that this seems vague, but all databases are different and are used in different ways. You only need to regularly rebuild/defrag indexes that incur write operations (inserts/updates) – your static or mostly read only tables will not need much reindexing.

You will need to use `dbcc showcontig([Table])` to check the fragmentation level of your indexes, determine how often they become fragmented and as to what level the fragmentation actually is.

Use `dbcc dbreindex([Table])` to totally rebuild the indexes when they become too fragmented (above 20%-30% or so) but if you cannot find a large enough downtime window and the fragmentation level is relatively low (1%-25%), you should use `dbcc indexdefrag([Database], [Table], [Index])` to defrag the index in an "online" fassion. Also keep in mind, that you can stop the index defrag operation and start it again at a later time without losing any work.

Keeping a database and its indexes "in tune" takes a bit of monitoring to really get a feel for when and what to reindex.

Comment: I am admittedly an old-school SQL guy. Please leave some detail.... Enlighten me.

Comment: Because they are marked as deprecated starting with SQL Server 2005 and will be removed in a future version. Here are just 2 URLs mentioning this: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/tarad/archive/2007/02/26/60121.aspx & http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1352 and here is the official word of wisdom: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx

Comment: I've got to say, sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats is far superior to showcontig. Thanks for the info!!

Answer (score 1):

Given the size of your database, you can easily rebuild the indexes once per month. But as the size increases, say to around 500 GB, you could do it twice per month.

Comment: Depending, of course, on the number of open transactions, their types and lifetimes. This could be a VERY active 10GB database.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned in [Bacon Bits comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275516/how-often-should-the-indexes-be-rebuilt-in-our-sql-server-database#comment90496950_2275739)  [Ola Hallengren's SQL Server Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/)  IndexOptimize is supported on SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2014, SQL Server 2016, SQL Server 2017, SQL Server 2019, Azure SQL Database, and Azure SQL Database Managed Instance.
It has 2K stars on https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution.

Michelle Ufford (a.k.a. "SQL Fool") 's [automated index defrag script](http://sqlfool.com/2009/03/automated-index-defrag-script/), suggested in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2275739/52277), conceptually seems does the same as  Ola Hallengren's SQL Server Maintenance Solution, but the latest version is in 2011.