# 2scx very slow when saving content

Tags: sql, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

We're having an issue with one of our sites. It's a large DNN Platform site version 8.0.4, with close to 1000 pages of content that is close to going into production. We have been using 2sxc 9.10 to manage the content on the site, unfortunately it's now grinding to a halt whenever we try to save content.

It appears that the SQL queries that are causing the problems are ones that are joining between 2 tables (i.e EAV_Attributes and EAV_EntityRelationships OR EAV_Values and EAV_Attributes). These queries also have hundreds (sometimes thousands) of records after 'WHERE IN'.

We have tried indexing a couple of the tables EAV_Values and EAV_EntityRelationships. This did speed it up a bit, but unfortunately not to a usable speed.

The issue seems to be exasperated when there are multiple users editing content on the site.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: We ended up doubling the amount of RAM available on the server to 8gb. This seems to have fixed things for the moment. We don't believe the issue has fully gone away, but the server is dealing better with the queries being executed than it was before.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the next release of 2sxc will have save-performance improvements of ca. factor 10 :)
Release probably end of march.

Comment: 2sxc 9.30 is out, and it's up to 100x faster at saving in such scenarios :)

Answer (score 0):

We've have a lot of pages too and had this issue. I ended up re-indexing the whole database based on Raphael's suggestion. That solved our issue. I now re-index on a schedule.

See my write-up here: [Intermittant Exceptions On Save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358621/intermittant-exceptions-on-save/42120100#42120100)