# In Entity Framework code-first, why are primary keys always stored as clustered indexes?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I'm learning more about indexes in general, and clustered indexes in particular.

[In this article by Markus Winand](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2014-01/unreasonable-defaults-primary-key-clustering-key), he makes an excellent case for **not** using the primary key of a table as the clustering key.

He stresses index-only scans over using clustered indexes, and shows how you can use non-clustered indexes to get really fast results.

Can someone explain why Entity Framework code-first does not provide the means to store a table as a non-clustered-index?

What are the benefits of having every table clustered?

Comment: How about creating UNIQUE and NOT NULL column and do not use PK at all? Will EF Code First create clustered index then?

Comment: I understand you're thrilled about this stellar blog post, but I'm afraid the questions you're asking are too broad for Stack Overflow. For one, it's always a guessing game to answer questions about implementation decisions of third-party libraries. Usually the only possible answer is: ask them.

Comment: @lad2025 that's an interesting idea. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20404899/660223 as well. I'm going to try it out and see what happens.

Comment: Read everything Kimberly Tripp (the *Queen of Indexing*) has written on the topic: [The Clustered Index Debate - continued](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/), [Ever-increasing clustering key – the Clustered Index Debate……….again!](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/); She explains in great detail **why** a well-chosen clustering key makes **all operations** (***YES*** - even insert and delete!) faster in SQL Server

Comment: Once you've read and digested all of Kimberly Tripp's excellent advice, you'll quickly see that putting the clustering index on the primary key *is* in fact a very wise and useful default. Agreed - there are cases when it might not work out - but those are relatively rare. As a **default**, putting the CI on your PK is a *good and sane* choice.

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the resource. It's good to have more perspective and take all factors into the equation.

Comment: @lad2025 if you don't care about Orphan records and consistency of your db, then yes, you don't need PK

Comment: @RuslanTolkachev You could easily create FK to UNIQUE column. So your argument is invalid. **[Demo](http://rextester.com/KTK24307)**